# How to start vue server on boot with raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, vue.js, raspberry-pi, debian

I usually start the vue server with `npm run serve`, but i want to make it start itself at boot time of raspberry pi and i don't know how to do it. I want it to be accessible from my local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi runs as a UNIX machine, so you can use typical entrypoint mechanisms to start your server on boot.

I'd recommend editing your `rc.local` to run your `npm run serve` in your `terminal`:

`sudo non /etc/rc.local`

Add on a new line:

`(cd /path/to/vueapp && npm run serve) &`

**The additional & at the end forks the process, don't forget this.**

then run `sudo reboot` and you should see your local server running on startup.